# How can I setup a router to assign IP addresses to all connections through a 24-port hub?

Tags: router, lan, dhcp, ip-address

How can I do that? Also is there any router that is already ready to handle something like that? Is there any other recommended setup to solve this problem. This is a relatively low budget (probably less than $200.00). We already have a 24-port hub. We need to get a router with DHCP that can handle something like this. I am not sure which router can do this, nor do I know how to set this up properly. Any help would be much appreciated! :)

This setup is for a lan-party!
Thanks!

Comment: Get the dudes to bring their switches and uplink them, unless you want packet-collision-o-rama.

Comment: Are actually using a 'hub', or using a switch and just calling it a hub? It doesn't impact the answer to your specific question, but I would suggest that if you're using an actual hub, you upgrade to a switch for performance reasons. Using a hub will result in many network collisions, reducing your network throughput. Basically, a hub will broadcast all the packets to all the ports (think of a room full of people, each yelling to each other trying to have a converstation), whereas, a switch will intelligently route packets to the proper ports on the the device.

Comment: Actually, it is a switch and I am just calling it a hub.

Comment: "_Actually, it is a switch and I am just calling it a hub._" Don't do that! There is a huge difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A router should handle everything through a hub, as long as no other machine connected to the hub has a DHCP server on it already.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have enough available addresses in your DHCP configuration, most routers will handle it.  If most of the traffic is local, you should be fine.  Some very low-end consumer grade routers will have issues with handling 24 computers all reaching out to the internet for information at the same time.

I have personally witnessed issues with as few as 9 devices.  8 devices on the network and all was well, as soon as a 9th device was added, everything went sideways.  It was hard to diagnose also due to the proliferation of wireless devices.  Through the day, everything was fine.  As soon as the husband came home with his Android phone, the router could not handle it.  And due to Android intermittently turning wifi on and off depending on whether the phone was idle, it became even more screwy.  Just a word of warning.

This was with an older model Linksys WRT54G.